# Installing brackets needed libgcrypt11 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dependencies

I was trying to install Brackets on Ubuntu 16.04. It seeks the dependency on libgcrypt11. I installed that as well from the [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb).

Now everything is working fine. But I just wanted to know if I can change the dependency of Brackets to libgcrypt20.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 3):

Due to the dependency issue of libgcrypt, the solution can be found here

https://brbsix.github.io/2015/10/29/fix-missing-libgcrypt11-for-brackets-text-editor/

Brief steps:

> 1. Unpack Brackets
> 2. Remove the package’s dependence on libgcrypt11
> 3. Copy the library into the unpacked package directory
> 4. Rebuild the package
> 5. Install

Comment: How and why are you assuming that Bracket will function exactly without gcrypt? gcrypt is required for handshaking things over the internet afaik and there should be some missing functionaliy normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest fixed Brackets .deb files from here: https://fourthfruit.github.io/fixes/ where it explains the fixed Brackets file or you may skip all of that and download it directly from here: [http://mega.nz/#!U3I0gRpY!9oJQ7E6Npz-3IK3mCrf1pKxM3lKybXLUq-c6QdWTu‌​N4](http://mega.nz/#!U3I0gRpY!9oJQ7E6Npz-3IK3mCrf1pKxM3lKybXLUq-c6QdWTu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BN4)

Comment: Oops... fixing it now!

Comment: you can go directly to it here : https://mega.nz/#!U3I0gRpY!9oJQ7E6Npz-3IK3mCrf1pKxM3lKybXLUq-c6QdWTuN4  but I will also be fixing the github.io page.

Comment: You should probably disclose your affiliation with the web site linked in your answer. Posting links to affiliated sites without disclosure is considered spam on Ask Ubuntu (see https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion).

Comment: On the page it says that you should not talk about or use your your website too much. The only reason I put it through that site is because it explains what the file is for and such. There is no marketing or advertising involved with the site given as there is none on the site. The fourthfruit.github.io site was created purely for educational and helpful purposes to assist those requiring help with Brackets on Ubuntu 16.04+ as it is a large issue.

Comment: I understand that but it would help to fend off trigger-happy flag raisers and reviewers if you show them that you're aware of the rules and restrictions on self-promotion. :-) (You can also delete your earlier comments once they're obsolete, e. g. if the problem was resolved and/or the info added to the parent post.)